# how to unhide textfield from skscene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, uitextfield, nsnotificationcenter

I'm in my SKScene and I want to unhide a text field in the presenting view controller.  I'm using NSNotificationCenter to call a function in my view controller and I've even seen the code arrive at the function and pass the line where the textfield is unhidden, but for some strange reason it doesn't appear.  Any thoughts?

Here is the output from the lldb:

```
<UIWindow: 0x7bf3dbb0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7bf4dd60>; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7bf364c0>>
   | <UITransitionView: 0x833c34e0; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x833c3720>>
   |    | <SKView: 0x7c86de00; frame = (0 0; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; autoresizesSubviews = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x7d48e4c0>; layer = <CAEAGLLayer: 0x7bf38d20>>
   |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bf475f0; frame = (227 458; 64 90); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf47120>>
   |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x837dca00; frame = (0 0; 64 90); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x837dcae0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x837dcbf0; frame = (18 39.5; 28.5 13.5); text = 'Store'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x837dcd00>>
   |    |    | <OptionMenu: 0x7bf3b300; frame = (43 55; 114 493); hidden = YES; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf3b530>>
   |    |    |    | <UIView: 0x7bf2c1c0; frame = (0 0; 600 600); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf2c560>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x7d433820; frame = (0 0; 600 600); autoresize = RM+BM; tag = 1; layer = <CALayer: 0x7d42a2c0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7bf2b0f0; frame = (38 15; 562 42); text = ''; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7bf2c280>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UILabel: 0x7d43b1f0; frame = (49 88; 321 334); text = 'Dear Samuel,

I'll be spe...'; opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x7d43a6e0>>
   |    |    |    |    | <UIButton: 0x7bf2e790; frame = (31 15; 50 50); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf3c120>>
   |    |    |    |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x837dc5e0; frame = (0 0; 50 50); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x837dc6c0>> - (null)
   |    |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7bf3bf50; frame = (0 0; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf645c0>>
   |    |    | <_UILayoutGuide: 0x7bf3bb30; frame = (0 568; 0 0); hidden = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7bf29910>>
   |    |    | <UITextField: 0x833bf810; frame = (20 150; 280 31); text = ''; clipsToBounds = YES; alpha = 0; opaque = NO; tag = 2; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x83470100>; layer = <CALayer: 0x833bfb10>>
   |    |    |    | <_UITextFieldRoundedRectBackgroundViewNeue: 0x833c19f0; frame = (0 0; 280 31); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x833c1bf0>> - (null)
   |    |    |    | <UITextFieldLabel: 0x833c1220; frame = (7 2; 266 27); text = 'Password'; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <_UILabelLayer: 0x833c1330>>
```

Comment: Are you sure your text field is above your `SKScene` (and any other possibly obscuring views) in your view hierarchy?

Comment: I added a line that said:   [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.text_field_view].  I created my textfield programmatically FYI.  Shouldn't the above mentioned line ensure the textfield is on top in the hierarchy?  I also tried adding the field in the main storyboard.

Comment: In the debugger, run `po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]`. Paste the output into your question.

Comment: I pasted the output above and it seems that the last layer added is the textfield, BUT it says that it's not opaque and that userInteraction is not enabled which doesn't make sense since I set both of these to YES before even adding them to the view.

Comment: I figured out my issue.  My NSNotificationCenter function was being called after the touchesBegan function from UITextFieldDelegate was called which would reset my text field to hidden.